# Fit image to page and auto hide scrollbar

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imagescrollviewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <!--<Viewbox>-->
        <Image x:Name="im" Source="{Binding JpgImageSource}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding Value,ElementName=scaleslider}" ScaleY="{Binding Value,ElementName=scaleslider}"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <!--</Viewbox>-->
    </ScrollViewer>
<Slider x:Name="scaleslider" Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Maximum="4" Minimum="0.2" Value="1"/>
```

1. The scrollbar doesn't adpat to the image size properly. When the image gets bigger, the scrollbar should be shorter and vice versa. Is there some way to figure out the problem?
2. How to know the slider value when the image is fit to the window?

Comment: you can't use viewbox for that

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml , i have tried, but did not find the difference

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to use `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`. [This blog post](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/19/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference.html) describes the difference very well.

```
<Image x:Name="im" Source="{Binding JpgImageSource}" >
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding Value,ElementName=scaleslider}" ScaleY="{Binding Value,ElementName=scaleslider}"/>
    </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: thanks,@Marc,the LayoutTransform did work. does the scrollviewer have its own size,  i want to set image to fit to window